# Javascript - what does value before function in anonymous function call construction?

Tags: javascript, callback, anonymous-function, material-ui, parentheses

I found this in sources of Material UI

```
(0, _classCallCheck3.default)(this, Drawer);
```

For instance

```
var c = function (a, b) {console.log(a, b)};
(5, c)(1, 2); // prints '1 2', but what is 5 doing?
```

Comment: Please format your code properly next time.

Comment: And this looks like the comma operator is just throwing away the first argument, making it evaluate to the second.

Comment: The 5 does nothing at all. The expression evaluates to the rightmost item if separated by commas and is the same as writing `5;  c(1,2);`